# Excel VBA: More efficient way to compare values with formulas for large range

Tags: vba, excel

I have large table with values in range H2:PIG2202. I need to compare the first rows H2:PIG2 values with all other rows values. And if there is a match in the result table it pastes just those values which matched. 
Now I'm using this formula in the result table to display needed values:

```
=IF(sheet!H$2=sheet!H3;IF(AND(sheet!H3;ISBLANK(sheet!H3))=FALSE;sheet!H3;"");"")
```

The VBA code is:

```
Sub find()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("H2:PIG2202").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF('sheet'!R2C='sheet'!R[1]C,IF(AND('sheet'!R[1]C,ISBLANK('sheet'!R[1]C))=FALSE,'sheet'!R[1]C,""""),"""")"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that Excel shows an error when I run this macros that there are not enough system resources.

Also I would like that in the result table would be just values, not formulas.

Is that possible to do? I have no idea how to achieve this :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you know that you are entering formula to range [11050 columns x 2200 rows] = 24.310.000 cells. I have a very good machine and problem to do so as well. Are you sure you logic is ok?

Comment: I know just the only one solution how to achieve what I need - using formulas. That is why I'm asking for another solution to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution for your which is not sophisticated and I'm rather not proud of it (but it was quickest to prepare). Keep in mind that you are going to run it 24m times which could take several minutes, maybe an hour. Some comments inside the code.

```
Sub Solution()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'-----previous one
'Range("H2:PIG2202").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF('sheet'!R2C='sheet'!R[1]C,IF(AND('sheet'!R[1]C,ISBLANK('sheet'!R[1]C))=FALSE,'sheet'!R[1]C,""""),"""")"

'----- new one- inserting values- first idea, simple code

Dim Cell As Range
'run for one row first to check if it is ok! and check time needed per row
'next change range to one you expect
'next- take a cup of coffee and relax...

For Each Cell In Range("h2:PIG2")
    Cell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF('sheet'!R2C='sheet'!R[1]C,IF(AND('sheet'!R[1]C,ISBLANK('sheet'!R[1]C))=FALSE,'sheet'!R[1]C,""""),"""")"
    Cell.Value = Cell.Value
    'to trace progress in Excel status bar
    Application.StatusBar = Cell.Address
Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't crash AND does what expected AND didn't take too long to calc all the values AND that is just great a solution for me! Huge thanks to you!